# The smallest Palindrome number is greater N

Tags: java, palindrome

For a given positive integer N of not more than 1000000 digits, write the value of the smallest palindrome larger than N to output.

Here is my code:

```
public class Palin {

    public static String reverseString(String s) {
        String newS = "";
        for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            newS += s.charAt(i);
        return newS;
    }

    public static String getPalin(String s) {
        int lth = s.length();

        String left = "", mid = "", right = "", newS = "";
        if(lth % 2 != 0) {
            left = s.substring(0, lth / 2);
            mid = s.substring(lth / 2, lth / 2 + 1);
            right = reverseString(left);

            newS = left + mid + right;

            if(s.compareTo(newS) < 0) return newS;
            else {
                int temp = Integer.parseInt(mid);
                temp++;
                mid = Integer.toString(temp);
                newS = left + mid + right;
                return newS;
            }
        }
        else {
            left = s.substring(0, lth / 2 - 1);
            mid = s.substring(lth / 2 - 1, lth / 2);
            right = reverseString(left);

            newS = left + mid + mid + right;
            if(s.compareTo(newS) < 0) return newS;
            else {
                int temp = Integer.parseInt(mid);
                temp++;
                mid = Integer.toString(temp);
                newS = left + mid + mid + right;
                return newS;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int k = input.nextInt();
        String[] s = new String[k];

        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            s[i] = input.next();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            System.out.println(getPalin(s[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

My idea is use a String represent for a number. I divide this String into 2 part, coppy first part and reverse it for second part. I think my solve is correct but it not fast enough. I need a more efficient algorithm. 
Thanks

Comment: Your `reverseString` is inefficient. Use a `StringBuilder` to reverse the String : `new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString()`

Comment: If your code works your in the wrong place, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: @Eran Thank for suggest. Can you tell me how the **reverse()** method work??

Comment: @Puskin you can look at the implementation of StringBuilder (or actually AbstractStringBuilder). It reverses an array of characters.

Comment: @Eran: yeah, and i want to know how to reverses an array because i think swap 2 element 1 - n, 2 - (n-1), .. and so on is the best.

Comment: @Puskin that's true (only it's 0 with n-1, 1 with n-2, ...)

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**
Since you said that:

> For a given positive integer N of not more than **1000000 digits**

My previous solution won't work since I have converted them to `int` and an `int` can't accommodate **1000000 digits**. Thus I have made a new approach, an approach that doesn't need any String to int conversion.

Refer to the code and comment below for details.

CODE:

```
package main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int k = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        String[] s = new String[k];

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            s[i] = input.nextLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            System.out.println(getPalin(s[i]));
        }

        input.close();

    }

    public static String getPalin(String s) {
        // initialize the result to "" since if input is 1 digit, nothing is printed
        String result = "";

        // if input is greater than 1000000 digits
        if (s.length() >= 1000000) {
            // return the highest palindrome less than 1000000
            result = "999999";
        } else if (s.length() > 1) {
            // get the middle index of the string
            int mid = s.length() % 2 == 0 ? s.length() / 2 : (s.length() / 2) + 1;

            // get the left part of the string
            String leftPart = getPalindrome(s.substring(0, mid));

            if (s.length() % 2 == 0) {
                // attach the left part and the reverse left part
                result = leftPart + new StringBuilder(leftPart).reverse().toString();
            } else {
                // attach the left part and the reverse left part excluding the middle digit
                result = leftPart
                        + new StringBuilder(leftPart.substring(0, leftPart.length() - 1)).reverse().toString();
            }

            // check if the new result greater than 1000000 digits
            if (result.length() >= 1000000) {
                // return the highest palindrome less than 1000000
                result = "999999";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String getPalindrome(String param) {
        String result = "";

        // iterate through the string from last index until index 0
        for (int i = param.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // get the char at index i
            char c = param.charAt(i);

            /*
             * increment char since the next palindrome is the current digit + 1. Example:
             * User input is 121, then param will be 12 so the next is 13
             */
            c++;

            /*
             * check if the current character is greater than '9', which means it is not a
             * digit after incrementing
             */
            if (c > '9') {
                // set the current char to 0
                c = '0';
                // check if index is at index 0
                if (i - 1 < 0) {
                    // if at index 0 then add '1' at start
                    result = '1' + result;
                } else {
                    // if not then append c at result
                    result = result + c;
                }
            } else {
                // check if index is at index 0
                if (i - 1 < 0) {
                    // if not then prepend c at result
                    result = c + result;
                } else {
                    // if not then get the rest of param then append c and result
                    result = param.substring(0, i) + c + result;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, your idea is like me. Only the **reverse** method is diffirence. I wrote a function and you used StringBuilder

Comment: @Mark code without containing a single loop does not necessarily mean it's complexity is O(1). you've to understand underlying built in functions. like you can use built in sort() method but that would also take O(nlogn) complexity. Here you are using .reverse() which is using a loop internally. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: @AsifRahaman as what I have said "as close as to O(1)". I didn't say that it is O(1) since I know that we have to understand underlying built in functions.

Comment: @Puskin We have the same approach but your code fails for input that are 1 digit. :)

Comment: @Mark then how it's actually different? plus every time you are using ParseInt which uses loop too!

Comment: @AsifRahaman You doesn't seem to understand my comment. As I said I didn't claim that it is O(1) since I know that the underlying functions may have loops. But I have edited my answer to not include the claim

Comment: @Mark. No, At first i thought like you, but i ran it and it was absolutely right even with input are 1 digit @@

Comment: @Puskin`I have made a new edit since you said that ***N of not more than 1000000 digits***, kindly check

Comment: @Mark: I have got a problem . Is a one-digit number a palindrome number. That is why you told my code fails for input that are 1 digit ???

Comment: @Puskin No, 1 digit numbers are not palindrome numbers. But in your question if the user input's ```1``` the program should output the smallest palindrome number  greater ```N```, thus your program should output 11.

Comment: @Mark: this case is yes. 1 digit number is palindrome. But i don't know why i don't accepted. this is link: https://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/ . can you consider for me. Thank